# Use a date within a query to select which monthly table to query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, conditional-statements

I'm new and asking for help

Within ACCESS
(Amongst a tangled web of mapping tables)

I have a table of approvals that has the date they were set up.

I have a years worth of separate monthly HR staff lists that are snapshots including line mangers grade and where people were working etc.

I need to bring back everyone's location on the date they applied for approval.

Put it another way?

I have a range of [approval.dates] going back 3 years in one table (I'm only interested in the previous 12 months)
I need to search the [monthly reports] for each approval date and bring back a [monthlyreport.location] at that date.

Each approval date can only match to a month not a specific date.

Conditionally choosing which table to reference is the most succinct way I can put it.

Thank you for reading, I hope it made a bit of sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please rewrite your post to include sample data, what you have already attempted to do yourself and found to not work, and what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp. Have a look at that this

Comment: I've taken a long time to make sense of the data sets involved and it would take an essay on here to explain. "join a load to the left and ignore" is what i needed to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "conditional join" but you can join to a bunch of things with a left join and ignore the wrong ones.

You give no details of your case so I will make it up:

```
select coalesce(jan.field, feb.field, mar.field, ... dec.field, 0) as result
from atable a
left join jan on a.id = jan.id and a.month = 'jan'
left join feb on a.id = jan.id and a.month = 'feb'
left join mar on a.id = jan.id and a.month = 'mar'
-- ...
left join dec on a.id = jan.id and a.month = 'dec'
```

This will retrieve the "field" column of the month table for the specific month referenced in atable.month.

Comment: thnaks for trying to decypher my issue.